# A easier and efficient way to do this?

Tags: java

Ok, id consider myself knowing the basics and some advanced Java but still dont have the courage to start programming my ideas that I have. This is a simple programme i came up with that basically outputs the amount of specific letter your text has (i think i worded that wrong...) this is my code:

```
public class gene {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] phrases = {"hello", "egg", "learning", "ferrero", "rocher",
            "Horologe", "Twinling"};
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    int c=0;
    int d=0;
    int e=0;
    int f=0;
    int g=0;
    int h=0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    int m=0;
    int n=0;
    int o=0;
    int p=0;
    int q=0;
    int r=0;
    int s=0;
    int t=0;
    int u=0;
    int v=0;
    int w=0;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int z=0;

    for(int ii =0; ii <phrases.length; ii++){
    char[] charphrases = phrases[ii].toCharArray();
    for(int iii = 0; iii<charphrases.length; iii++){
        switch(charphrases[iii]){
        case ('a'):
            a++;
        break;          
    case ('b'):
        b++;
    break;
    case ('c'):
        c++;
    break;
    case ('d'):
        d++;
    break;
    case ('e'):
        e++;
    break;
    case ('f'):
        f++;
    break;
    case ('g'):
        g++;
    break;
    case ('h'):
        h++;
    break;
    case ('i'):
        i++;
    break;
    case ('j'):
        j++;
    break;
    case ('k'):
        k++;
    break;
    case ('l'):
        l++;
    break;
    case ('m'):
        m++;
    break;
    case ('n'):
        n++;
    break;
    case ('o'):
        o++;
    break;
    case ('p'):
        p++;
    break;
    case ('q'):
        q++;
    break;
    case ('r'):
        r++;
    break;
    case ('s'):
        s++;
    break;
    case ('t'):
        t++;
    break;
    case ('u'):
        u++;
    break;
    case ('v'):
        v++;
    break;
    case ('w'):
        w++;
    break;
    case ('x'):
        x++;
    break;
    case ('y'):
        y++;
    break;
    case ('z'):
        z++;
    break;
        }
    }
    }

    System.out.println("A:" + a + "\n" + "B:" + b + "\n" +"C:" + c + "\n" +"D:" + d + "\n" +"E:" + e + "\n" +"F:" + f + "\n" +"G:" + g + "\n" +"H:" + h + "\n" +"I:" + i+ "\n" +"J:" + j + "\n" +"K:" + k + "\n" +"L:" + l + "\n" +"M:" + m + "\n" +"N:" + n + "\n" +"O:" + o + "\n" +"P:" + p + "\n" +"Q:" + q + "\n" +"R:" + r+ "\n" +"S:" + s + "\n" +"T:" + t + "\n" +"U:" + u + "\n" +"V:" + v + "\n" +"W:" + w + "\n" +"X:" + x + "\n" +"Y:" + y + "\n" +"Z:" + z + "\n" + z);
    }
```

}

As you can see, its it VERY long for such a simple programme and no doubt that there is a shorter way to write it. Can someone tell me where I can condense the programme to make it shorter and more efficient.

Comment: Please fix your title. It should describe the actual problem.

Comment: Learn about [arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). You can do this with an array, instead of 26 separate variables.

Comment: nice place to go might be [http://codereview.stackexchange.com/](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) here, your code gets review. :)

Comment: Consider using a `Map`, where the key is a,b,c,etc

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
int[] count = new int[26];
```

you can do

```
for(char c: string.toCharArray())
    count[c - 'a']++;
```

Comment: what does the 'a' represent in the enhanced for loop method?

Comment: @Tloz the integer value of 'a' is substracted from the current character (c) and therefore accessing the right index of the counting array, e.g. 'a' - 'a' = Index 0, 'b' - 'a' = 1 and so on

Answer (score 2):

Instead of declaring 26 different `int` variables, declare one `int` array of length 26.  All elements here are automatically initialized to 0.

```
int[] letterCounts = new int[26];
```

Then, instead of 26 cases, take advantage of the fact that the numeric values for the letters are all in numerical order.  If you subtract `'a'` from your letter, you will get a value from 0 through 25 that represents the index you need.  Then you can say:

```
letterCounts[charphrases[iii] - 'a']++;
```

Depending on your requirements, you may need to handle other characters separately, such as capital letters, numbers, and/or punctuation.

Then you can loop over your array contents, adding `'a'` to reproduce the letter, and print the appropriate array element.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a 26-member array instead of 26 variables. We know what each index from 0-25 would represent (0 is 'A', 1 is 'B', 2 is 'C' and so forth... Then to increment that letter, its index can be found by converting the char into an integer. (The conversion will require you to have an ASCII reference on hand, any will do). Learning to convert between chars and ints is relatively straightforward as long as you understand the necessary offsets.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). A `Map` allows you to associate one piece of data with another, so if you can do something similar to:

```
Map<Character, Integer> characterCount = new LinkedHashMap<>();

Integer currentCount = characterCount.get('a');
if(currentCount == null) {
    currentCount = 0;
}
characterCount.put('a', currentCount++);
```

It's a bit wordier than using an array as others have suggested, but it is a lot more flexible if you no longer want to use a `char` somewhere later down the road.

Answer (score 0):

I made you a program using a `Map`. Check it out:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        System.out.println(map);
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for(char c : alphabet.toCharArray())
            map.put(c, 0);
         addString("Hello World", map);
         System.out.println(map);
  }

    public static void addString(String s, Map<Character, Integer> m){
        s = s.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "");
        for(char c : s.toCharArray())
            m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you have a character such as ü in your string?

Comment: All you need to do is update `alphabet` to contain the characters you'd like to record. But yeah, I should have put a try catch, or tested if the value in the map was null.

Answer (score 0):

I've improved mjkaufers answer and this is what you can do to count any characters (including UTF-8 and special characters):

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        countCharacters("Hello World", map);
        System.out.println(map);
    }

    public static void countCharacters(String s, Map<Character, Integer> m) {
        s = s.replace(" ", ""); // do not count spaces

        // if you only want to count lower case characters:
        // s = s.toLowerCase();

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            int cnt = (m.get(c) == null) ? 0 : m.get(c);
            m.put(c, cnt + 1);
        }
    }
}
```